# Close all pnotify notifications when a specific notification shows up

Tags: jquery, pnotify

I am using pnotify plugin. My code is as follows:

```
$('.input_elements').on('change', function() {
   if ($(this).val() > 2) {
      $.pnotify({
         text: 'Quantity exceeds the number of available items.',
         type: 'error',
         delay: 2500,
         history: false,
         sticker: true
      });
   } else {
      $.pnotify({
         text: 'Saved.',
         type: 'success',
         delay: 2500,
         history: false,
         sticker: true
      });
   }
});
```

My question is, how can I make all other visible notifications on page go away when this notification shows up on `.input_elements` change event. Is there an option on pnotify that makes it go away if another is opened?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use PNotify.removeAll() to remove all the notifications.

Comment: any idea how to remove all notifications but not some specific ones?

Comment: @baltusaj Whenever you create a notification set an attribute called name which will be unique for each notification. Then use PNotify.notices to list all the notices, Then based on an if condition you can remove that particular notice by calling .remove on it. eg: PNotify.notices[notice_to_be_removed].remove();